# Permission denied error in AWSTATS (IIS Server)

Tags: iis-7, logfiles, awstats

I am using AWStats on windows server (IIS7)
Everting is working fine but when I click the Update Now link which takes me to the next page where I am hit with this error:

Error: Couldn't open server log file "C:\HostingSpaces\domain.com\logs\W3SVC8\u_ex130520.log" : Permission denied
Setup ('C:\home\AWStats\cgi-bin/awstats.www.domain.com.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).

There are a number of log files, one for each day in this folder W3SVC8.

I have tried adding permission to the logs directory but it didn't work.

What do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Look up chmod to change permissions on the log file.  Try 755, then 775, then 777 on that log file.

Comment: actually, awstats is installed on windows server. Also, I have tried to change permissions, but it does not work...

Comment: The issue is with AWStats reading your server log.  Check the settings in your config file.  Also, modify the permissions on your log files as well, not just the directory.